# Obter valor de uma célula de Excel com OpenPyxl (Python)

Tags: python, openpyxl

Possuo uma planilha em Excel que estou analisando alguns dados, e quando faço esse loop, o valor retornado é uma string, como `'=AL35/AH35'` por exemplo, ao invés de um float.

Esse conjunto de células que estou me referindo tem essa fórmula e na planilha o resultado é uma porcentagem.

Ao fim do loop, estou guardando as informações em um arquivo .txt.

```
for i in range(4,37):    

        previsao = metas['Metas'].cell(row = i, column = 39).value      

        file.write(f"{previsao:>15}\n")
```

Gostaria que a saída para o Python fosse um valor com ponto flutuante.

Answer (score -1):

Utilizando o parâmetro `data_only` ao abrir o workbook:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
```